# C#- Confirm, Password and Email text box shows me message box when I enter first character

Tags: c#, winforms

[image]

```
 //code for confirm password text box:

     private void txtRegPassConfirm_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                    if (txtRegPassConfirm.Text != txtRegPass.Text)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Passwords do not match");
                        txtRegPassConfirm.Clear();
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("textbox can not be empty");   
                    } 
                }


    //code for text box Password:

     private void txtRegPass_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

                if (txtRegPass.Text.Length < 8)
                {

                    MessageBox.Show("Password must be at least 8 characters long");
                    txtRegPassConfirm.Clear();
                }


  // code for text box Email:

     private void txtRegEmail_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            string c = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Constr"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(c);
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("EmailReg", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", this.txtRegEmail.Text);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                if (dr.HasRows == true)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Email = " + dr[4].ToString() + "is Already exist");
                    txtRegEmail.Clear();
                    break;
               }
                Regex r = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z0-9){1,20}@[a-zA-Z0-9){1,20}.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$");

                if (!r.IsMatch(txtRegEmail.Text))
                {
                    txtRegEmail.Clear();
                    MessageBox.Show("incorrect formate");
                }

            }

        }

//code for button Registration:

private void btnRegistration_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                string c = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Constr"].ConnectionString;
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(c);
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("RegistrationForm", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", txtRegUserN.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtRegPass.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Confirm", txtRegPassConfirm.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtRegEmail.Text);
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    if (dr.HasRows == true)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Data Inserted Succesfully");

                    }
                }

              if (dr.HasRows == false)
               {

                  MessageBox.Show("Access Denied, enter the correct fields");
               }

              else
              {
                  MessageBox.Show("Enter correct info");
              }
       }
```

When I execute the application and enter the password in a confirm text box, it shows me the message box on entering the first character 'Password don't match'. As well as shows me message in the Password text box 'Password must be at least 8 characters long'.  And as same as in the Email text box and I want to apply the Regex  but not working. I moved my code in the email section but, it shows me the 'Email is invalid' regex message box. Now, tell me what I can do get the message box when I enter the mismatch words not on entering the first character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Main Problem:**

You are checking your validation rules in `TextChanged` event of your text boxes. Some options that may help you to perform validation is listed here:

**Option1: validate in Click Event of Button**

You can check for validations in `Click` event of your register button some thing like this:

```
private void registerButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Check for password length           
    if (txtRegPass.Text.Length < 8)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Password must be at least 8 characters long");
        txtRegPass.Focus();
        return;
    }

    //Check for other validations
    //...
    // don't forget to return; if the state is not valid


    //If the code execution reaches here, it means all validation have been passed
    //So you can save data here.
}
```

**Option 2: Use Validating Event and ErrorProvider**

As a better solution, you can use an `ErrorProvider`. Put an error provider in form and handle `Validatin` event of your TextBoxes and set error for that control.

Then in Click event of your register button you can check if there is any validation error or not.

and here a screenshot:

[image]

```
private void ValidationTest_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.AutoValidate = System.Windows.Forms.AutoValidate.EnableAllowFocusChange;
}

private void passwordTextBox_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.passwordTextBox.TextLength < 8)
    {
        this.errorProvider1.SetError(this.passwordTextBox, "Password must be at least 8 character");
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
    else
    {
        this.errorProvider1.SetError(this.passwordTextBox, "");
    }
}

private void confirmTextBox_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.confirmTextBox.Text != this.passwordTextBox.Text)
    {
        this.errorProvider1.SetError(this.confirmTextBox, "Password and Confirm must be the same");
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
    else
    {
        this.errorProvider1.SetError(this.confirmTextBox, "");
    }
}

private void registerButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.ValidateChildren())
    {
        //Do registration here
    }
    else
    {
        var listOfErrors = this.errorProvider1.ContainerControl.Controls
                            .Cast<Control>()
                            .Select(c => this.errorProvider1.GetError(c))
                            .Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
                            .ToList();
        MessageBox.Show("please correct validation errors:\n - " +
            string.Join("\n - ", listOfErrors.ToArray()),
            "Error",  
            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Comment: I used your second option... when I enter the password it's showing me error icon and when I enter the wrong while I click on other text box it makes the cursor stuck on that text box...

Comment: @Warda Put this in `Load` event of form: `this.AutoValidate = System.Windows.Forms.AutoValidate.EnableAllowFocusChange;` as I did, or set it at design time.

Comment: I used as above you wrote the code..when I enter the password it shows me an error icon and when I enter the wrong while I click on other text box it makes the cursor stuck on that text box..

Comment: Did you set the forms `AutoValidate`  property to `EnableAllowFocusChange`?

Comment: No, I didn't but now when I set it's right... But it doesn't show me message box when I press the button registration between data is saving database..

Comment: To show the messagebox you should check `this.ValidateChildren()` and if it is false, you should show messagebox, that function returns false, only if you set `e.Cancel = true;` for a control, in `Validating` event.

Comment: Where do I check the this.ValidateChildren() ??? Regbtn you did code I also did in Regbtn... Not showing me message box for saving the data....

Comment: Yes in registration button, and you should pay attention to if there is really a validation error? and if you have set set e.Cancel = true; for a controls that have validation errors? and if your controls are directly put on your forms or In a panel?

Comment: @Warda you should trace your program and pay attention to the code I posted and what I said, and also check the output of `this.ValidateChildren()`

Comment: @Warda You are welcome, now you know a good way for validation in UI layer :)

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using `TextChanged` event and it raises every time you change the `Text`. You should check this on click of your button `Register`.

Not only this one, your all validations should be checked on the button click.

For the help of user, you can use a `Label` to show the the message while user is typing something, rather showing a `MessageBox`. That will be a smooth experience for user.

Comment: Just put all of your validations in `Click` event of `Register` button.

Comment: @Shaharyar While your offer is completely ok, but as a better answer you can check my [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33014773/3110834). +1

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you put your validation code in `txtRegPassConfirm_TextChanged_1` function. As the name of the function said, that function will be triggered whenever the text in `txtRegPassConfirm` textbox changed. That's why you get the `MessageBox` when you first type.

To solve your problem, put your validation code in the `Click event` of `Register button` instead of `TextChanged` event of each textbox.

Another better solution is: use `Error Provider Control` to show your error instead of using `MessageBox`. To know more about it, take a look at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.errorprovider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Double click on your `Register` button, Visual Studio will auto generate a function which will be called when users click that button. Put your code there.

Comment: Yeah!!! I know this @Anhtriet... but I'm already using the using insert query for saving...

Comment: I mean your validation code, the code in those `TextChanged` functions :) Add it before the code for saving your data.

Comment: @AnhTriet I've provided a good [sample](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33014773/3110834) of using error provider, hope you find it helpful:) +1 for your good offer to OP.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your solution

```
private void btnRegistration_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
               if (txtRegPassConfirm.Text != txtRegPass.Text)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Passwords do not match");
                    txtRegPassConfirm.Clear();
                    return;
                }

                else
                {
                    if (txtRegPass.Text.Length < 8)
                    {

                        MessageBox.Show("Password must be at least 8 characters long");
                        txtRegPassConfirm.Clear();
                        return;
                    }

                } 
      //put your next code as it is which you wrote in this click event
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Please mark or tick this answer so that other person can know about this problem..It's my pleasure to help you

Comment: While your offer is completely ok, you can check my [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33014773/3110834). +1

Comment: Thank @RezaAghaei... :)

Answer (score 1):

The validation can also be done while moving to the next text box(Validation of previous text box input)  by pressing tab or by mouse click. This can be done in the textbox events Leave or Enter.

```
private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)  // This event is triggered while leaving the textbox1
    {
        if ("a" != textBox1.Text)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid");
        }
    }

private void textBox2_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)// This event is triggered while entering the textbox2
{
    if ("a" != textBox1.Text)    //Content of textbox1 is validated
    {
       MessageBox.Show("Invalid");
    }
}
```

Comment: Checking this way is not correct and you should use Validating event instead.

Comment: Hi Reza Aghaei - Agree with your point. +1 for your sample. Thanks:)