# is there a cleaner method of handling textbox validating events

Tags: vb.net, winforms, validation, error-handling

I have 20+ textboxes on a form and I am wondering if there is a cleaner method that I can use to handle the validation of these controls other than using the intended validating event handlers.

What I have tried is looping through all of the controls on the form checking them for their proper valid values and displaying the ErrorProvider on the proper control if the value is not valid thus cutting down the 20+ event handlers into 30 lines of code. this process is in a function that will return either true or false that is called on a button click and will proceed with more logic if returns true.

I am wondering if this is improper or if I should just stick to the validating event handlers

Comment: Both methods can be appropriate depending on the app and situation.  Sometimes you use a bit of both.  Some inputs might be able to be checked in the V Events, but with complex app logic - if the value of A controls the validity of B or is dependent on C - those might need to be done when the form is complete.  In that case, embed the logic in a class that perhaps scrapes the form (rather than putting the app logic in the form(s)).  Also check if you cant use "self validating" controls like the NumericUpDown for some.

Comment: Do you check for same validation rule for all text boxes?

Comment: Thanks Plutonix , and Reza, most of them yes aside from some isNumeric and specific lengths on certain textboxes. I am going with the custom function approach I just need to be able to grab textboxes inside a panel which is inside a groupbox aswell as any other textboxes on the form. I have the function grabbing any textboxes outside of a panel but can't seem to grab the ones inside yet.

Comment: For all of your textboxes that have a shared validation rule, you can use a single event handler method.

Comment: how would I specify a generic 'validating' handler to handle multiple textboxes

Comment: just register a single method for `Validating` event of them, using designer or code.

Comment: Let me know if it is what you are looking for and I'll post an answer based on this idea for you

Comment: yes please post an example using code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using the same validation rule for all (or most of) your text boxes (as stated in comments) you can assign a single handler to `Validating` event of those text boxes and validate them in that handler. For example:

```
Private Sub TXT_Validating(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) _
    Handles TextBox1.Validating, TextBox2.Validating, TextBox3.Validating

    'Find the validating control
    Dim txt As TextBox = DirectCast(sender, TextBox)

    'Check validation for that control
    If (txt.Text.Length > 10) Then

        'Set validation message if the state is invalid
        Me.ErrorProvider1.SetError(txt, "Maximum length of text is 10 characters.")

        'Say the state is invalid
        e.Cancel = True
    Else

        'Clear probable privious validation error for that textbox
        Me.ErrorProvider1.SetError(txt, String.Empty)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: can you elaborate a little bit on the e.Cancel , what do you mean by state is invalid

I ask this because say I have a button that is going to execute an insert statement, will the e.cancel prevent the action from happening if there are validation errors?

Comment: When you set `e.Cancel=true` you are saying that the validation has failed. So if you have set `AutoValidate` property of your form to `EnableAllowFocusChange` then it will prevent the focus change from that control. Also your form will use this value if you call `ValidateChildren` to check if all direct children of your form are valid.

Comment: You are welcome :) You may find this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33014773/3110834) helpful.

Comment: @gyt666 By the way, It would be great when you accept an answer, you kindly vote for it too by click on up arrow near the answer, it is not compulsory at all but recommended. While you can only accept one answer, but you can vote up as many answers as you find helpful, including the accepted one. You can also vote for good questions too :)

Comment: I have accepted both of your answers, including from my previous question though I have not voted up I will though as it seems to help :)

Comment: @gyt666 Thank you for your feedback :) as I said voting for accepted answer is not compulsory but reasonable and recommended and surely it is your kindness :)